# Turkish characters does not display correctly

Tags: html, css, character-encoding

i have the following code. it contain Turkish content. but i get the results including special charecter. so please give solution for that.

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="content-language" CONTENT="TR"  />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
Tarihçe
</body>
</html>
```

i will get `Tarih�e` instaed of `Tarihçe.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @deceze that answer was explain encodings in PHP

Comment: Just ignore anything that's specific to PHP and concentrate on the points that apply to static HTML equally well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Turkish encoding below will be the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
```

else code Tarihçe as

```
Tarih&ccedil;e
```

Comment: just tested in IE, Chrome and FireFox, its working for me, strange not working for you

Comment: yes it working but it does not support in footer of my web site

Comment: i got this output in footer Tarih�e

Comment: Second one should work for any encoding `Tarih&ccedil;e`

Comment: hey i have a lot of content. how to do that in all places

Comment: Either replace at all places or change the encoding of the page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52210/discussion-between-boopathi-and-hamed-ali-khan)

Comment: While entity references like `&ccedil;` work in all encodings, they are awkward to use and they make the HTML source very difficult to read. Besides, they just hide the real problem, the encoding mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Change the *actual* character encoding of the file to UTF-8, using whatever settings need to be used in the program you use to create and edit pages. The file is now in some 8-bit encoding, so the letter ç appears in the data as a byte that is not allowed in UTF-8; hence the � symbol (it indicates character-level data error).

Comment: Boopathi, that depends on the program you are using.